# Python -- Pandas : How to apply aggfunc to data in currency format?

Tags: python, pandas

```
Campaign ID Revenue Total
601         $2,690 
601         $817 
601         $0 
649         $4,339 
10901   $7,273
```

I have a table above . Want to apply groupby function to the data and apply sum ( over revenue_total) . Pandas gives an NA value since revenue_total is an object data type . Any help

```
import pandas as pd 
path = r"C:\Users\roy\Google Drive\Work\Backlog\test.csv" 
df = pd.read_csv(path) 
df[['Campaign ID','Revenue Total']].head() 
df.groupby(['Campaign ID'])[['Revenue Total']].sum()
```

Comment: How did you create the table frame? You need to post your code so people can see where the problem is

Comment: Here is my code :

import pandas as pd
path = r"C:\Users\roy\Google Drive\Work\Backlog\test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df[['Product ID ','Revenue Total']].head()
df.groupby(['Product ID '])[['Revenue Total']].sum()

and the values in Revenue Total for the output are all NaN

Comment: Code should be added as an edit to the question (and put in a code block). I don't know enough Python to do the edit for you, but as is it is not very helpful to potential answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data file looks like

```
Campaign ID  Revenue Total
601         $2,690 
601         $817 
601         $0 
649         $4,339 
10901   $7,273
```

Then you could remove the `$` and commas and parse it into a DataFrame using

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data', sep='\s{2,}',
                 converters={'Revenue Total':lambda x: x.lstrip('$').replace(',','')})
```

---

```
   Campaign ID Revenue Total
0          601          2690
1          601           817
2          601             0
3          649          4339
4        10901          7273
```

---

You might want to try just adding

```
converters={'Revenue Total':lambda x: x.lstrip('$').replace(',','')}
```

to your call to `pd.read_csv`. That is what is stripping the `$` and commas.

You probably do not need `sep='\s{2,}'` -- that was just to allow me to read in the data *given the format I showed above*. Your format is probably different but you didn't post it so I don't know what it is...

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with your data file.

If you do the following

- remove the "," and "$" from the dollar figures
- use ',' as seperate

Then running your code ...

```
import pandas as pd 
path = r"C:\Users\roy\Google Drive\Work\Backlog\test.csv" 
df = pd.read_csv(path) 
df[['Campaign ID','Revenue Total']].head() 
print  df.groupby(['Campaign ID'])[['Revenue Total']].sum()
```

will give this result

```
             Revenue Total
Campaign ID               
601                   3507
649                   4339
10901                 7273
```

Comment: I want the header =0 . The issue is dtype for Revenue Total is object and group by is not able to perform an agfunc on that.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Also as a reminder to newcomer to stackoverflow, it is important for you to upvote and/or accept answer. See explanation here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  Thanks.

Comment: Ok So the issue is to remove $ and ,. Then how do I do that